# Expected number of coin tosses to get a skewed score

Tags: probability

EDITED. You toss a fair coin $n$ times. After each toss $i$ you record the score so far: $s_i = (1000+totalHeadsRecorded)/(2000+i)$. 
What is the expected number for $n$ in order to get a score greater than some value $s$ ?

For $s<0.5$, $n$ should be $0$.
For $s>0.5$, $n$ appears to grow very quickly. I wonder when does it "jump" to either infinity or to "impossible", and what happens just before the jump? How big are those numbers?  For me, this problem seems somewhat similar to the Halting Problem.

Comment: $s$ can only be calculated after at least one "tails" occured.

Comment: How did you coclude that there is a relation to the halting problem and the busy beaver problem ?

Comment: I think the value is quite small. If you coss a fair coin $2000$ times, it is almost sure that you have at least $889$ times heads, which is already enough for the required score.

Comment: Considering a score of $1:0$ as infinite, I think the question meant to say that for $c < 0.5$, $n$ should be 1. (not $s < 0.5$.)

Comment: @MarkFischler I edited the question to simplify/clarify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a partial answer:

Let $X_i$ be the number of heads after $i$ tosses and $s$ your target ratio.

We can define a stochastic process $s_i:=\frac{1000+X_i}{2000+i}$

Define a stopping time, $\tau_s:=\{\inf i: s_i>s\}$

Note that $E[s_i|s_{i-1}]=0.5\left(s_{i-1}\frac{2000+i-1}{2000+i}\right)+0.5\left(s_{i-1}\frac{2000+i-1}{2000+i}+\frac{1}{2000+i}\right)=s_{i-1}\frac{2000+i-1}{2000+i}+\frac{1}{4000+2i}=s_{i-1}+\frac{1-2s_{i-1}}{4000+2i}$

As you've pointed out, $s<=0.5 \implies \tau_s=0$, so we can focus on the case $s>0.5$. Note that this process is not any type of martingale, as its conditional expectation can be above, at, or below the current value, depending on whether its current value is below, at, or above $0.5$ (i.e., we see regression towards the mean). However, it is both *approximately* and *asymptotically* a martingale.

Thus, you need to find $E[\tau_s]$ for $s>0.5$.

Let's define a new stopping time: $\tau'_s:=\{\inf i: s_i>s>0.5\text{ or } s_i<t<0.5\}$. Since $s_i$ is approximately a martingale, lets try using the [Optional Stopping Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optional_stopping_theorem), to conclude

$E[s_{\tau'_s}]\approx E[s_0]=0.5=sP(s_{\tau'_s}=s)+t[1-P(s_{\tau'_s}=s)]=(s-t)P(s_{\tau'_s}=s)-t$

Thus:

$P(s_{\tau'_s}=s) = \frac{0.5+t}{s-t}$ Since we only care about $s$, lets set $t=0$:

$P(s_{\tau'_s}=s) = \frac{1}{2s}$. Unfortunately, $t=0,s>0.5 \implies P(s_{\tau'_s}=0)>0 \implies E[\tau'_s]=\infty$

The assumption of approximate martingale was actually conservative, since the regression-to-mean behavior will simply slow the processes approach to the cutoff. It looks like you can expect to stop immediately, or never (although there is a positive probability of stopping sometime before forever).

Comment: If there is a positive probability of stoping, then there must be a finite stopping time, even for, say s=0.99. But the regression to mean makes it less likely to stop as n grows. For me, this is mind-boggling.

Comment: @Adrian this is a direct consequence of the strong law of large numbers. You are modeling a sequence of fair coin tosses and looking at how the ratio of heads to tails changes. SLLN implies that $P(\lim_{n \to \infty} s_i =0.5) = 1$, so for any $s\neq 0.5$, $s_i>s$ only a *finite* number of times. Now, if this weren't true, that would make statistics quite shaky...as we would have no justification for thinking that our sample average would approach the true value in a finite sample size.

Comment: @Adrian On the technical side...just because there is a finite probability of stopping doesn't mean that, on average, your stopping time is finite.

Comment: @Adrian In general, probability is full of instances where intuition is at odds with the actual case...that's the fun and challenge of probability :-)

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications and for calling it a partial answer. I assume that you we still don't know if $n$ is a well-defined number, and if yes, is it finite and computable? or in the same class as Busy Beavers?

Comment: @Adrian (correction...had $s\neq 0$, which is not correct) I'm saying partial because its not clear if it will totally answer your concerns. The expected number of trials is infinite for any $s\neq 0.5$. This is simply a consequence of the strong law of large numbers. So, n is defined, its just that $E[n]=\infty$